# Not being able to push multiple objects into the array using useState hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to push multiple objects into a state array using the useState hook but for some reason I cannot get it to work. I only get the latest object in the array instead of multiple objects.

Here's what the state looks like:

```
const [players, setPlayers] = useState([])
```

Here's how I am pushing the objects to the array:

```
const newPlayerObject = {address: newPlayer, level: newPlayerLevel, horse: newPlayerHorse}
setPlayers([...players, newPlayerObject])
```

But this only returns the array with the latest object instead of all the objects that are generated.

What am I doing wrong?

To give further context:

Here's the complete function:

```
const updatePlayer = async () => {
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
        const contract = new ethers.Contract(stallionRunAddress, abi, provider)
        const playerIndex = playersEntered - 1
        const newIndex = playerIndex.toString()

        const newPlayer = await contract.getPlayerAddress(newIndex)
        const newPlayerLevelBI = await contract.ownedHorseLevel(newPlayer)
        const newPlayerLevel = parseInt(newPlayerLevelBI)
        const newPlayerHorseArr = await contract.ownedHorseName(newPlayer)
        const newPlayerHorse = newPlayerHorseArr.toString()
        const newPlayerObject = {address: newPlayer, level: newPlayerLevel, horse: newPlayerHorse}
        setPlayers([...players, newPlayerObject])
    }
```

and I am calling it in a useEffect hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
        if(playersEntered > 0) {
            updatePlayer()
        }  
    }, [playersEntered])
```

And inside the return:

```
{players.length > 0 ? (
                    players.map((player, i) =>  {
                        return (
                            <div key={i} className="flex flex-row flex-wrap justify-center gap-x-10 md:gap-x-20 lg:gap-x-48 gap-y-2 md:gap-y-4 lg:gap-y-10 mt-4 text-red-400 font-semibold lg:text-xl">
                                <div>{player.address}</div>
                                <div>Level-{player.level}</div>
                                <div>Horse name: {player.horse}</div>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                ) : (<div className="text-center">No Players Yet</div>)}
```

Here's what the complete State looks like:

```
 const [inProgress, setInProgress] = useState(0)
    const [players, setPlayers] = useState([])
    const [playersEntered, setPlayersEntered] = useState(0)
    const [winner, setWinner] = useState("")
```

Comment: Please share more code because I think the given code will work fine.

Comment: What's `playersEntered`? I thought the state's name is just `players`.

Comment: Here's what the complete state looks like:
 const [inProgress, setInProgress] = useState(0)
    const [players, setPlayers] = useState([])
    const [playersEntered, setPlayersEntered] = useState(0)
    const [winner, setWinner] = useState("")

Comment: Alright. Regardless, failing to see the issue with the code. The only thing I suppose you could try is setting the state in the following matter: `setPlayers(prev => [...prev, newPlayerObject])`, as there might be a closure issue here. Not sure that is the case though.

Comment: Okay, Ill try that. Thanks for going through it

Comment: I think so, updatePlayer won't run in the first place since default value of playersEntered = 0   if(playersEntered > 0) { updatePlayer() }